# highcharts error 17 when creating a heatmap

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-4, highcharts, coffeescript

I'm trying to generate a heatmap using data inserted by `gon`.

The frame for the chart is generated correctly in the browser, but the chart is missing, just blank.

and in the console I get:

```
 Uncaught Highcharts error #17: www.highcharts.com/errors/17
```

which seems to be generated by the `initSeries` method in highcharts after a comment mentioning:

```
// No such series type
```

I'm using RoR4, with this in the `Gemfile`:

```
gem "highcharts-rails", "~> 3.0.0"
```

and this in the `application.js`:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require tether
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require highcharts
//= require highcharts/highcharts-more
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

my SLIM:

```
td
  .card
    .card-img-top(data-template-chart=true data-id=template.to_param)
```

my includes (from the compiled HTML):

```
 <script src="/assets/highcharts.self-d34c91baaad4188e2d81d954aa38de43ec4916882f39d2d908f86d47a6e942b0.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
 <script src="/assets/highcharts/highcharts-more.self-995bc649d8f9f68a0bb6bfb3242b35a20c494d716164fa0c93a74630b291113b.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
```

Inspecting the "sources" in the browser I can see both files being loaded

my coffeescript:

```
     $(window).bind 'page:change', ->
  initPage()

initPage= ->
  $('[data-template-chart]').each( ->
    curId = $(this).data("id")
    data = gon.templates[curId]
    $(this).highcharts
      chart: 
        height: 150
        width: 150
      title: text: ''
      xAxis:
        showLastLabel: false
        tickLength: 16
      yAxis:
        title: text: null
        labels: format: '{value}:00'
        minPadding: 0
        maxPadding: 0
        startOnTick: false
        endOnTick: false
        tickPositions: [0, 6, 12, 18, 24]
        tickWidth: 1
        min: 0
        max: 23
        reversed: true
      colorAxis:
        stops: [
          [0, '#3060cf']
          [0.5, '#fffbbc']
          [0.9, '#c4463a']
          [1, '#c4463a']
        ]
        min: -15
        max: 25
        startOnTick: false
        endOnTick: false
        # labels: format: value
      series: [
        {
          type: 'heatmap'
          data: csv: data
          borderWidth: 0
          nullColor: '#EFEFEF'
          colsize: 24 * 365
        }
       ]
)
```

I'm guessing the issue is with the `highcharts-more` library, which is being loaded in the browser, but it doesn't seem to be available, and I'm guessing it's a problem with the javascript generated by coffeescript.

This is the compiled version:

```
(function() {
  var initPage, update_form;

  $(function() {
    return initPage();
  });

  $(window).bind('page:change', function() {
    return initPage();
  });

  update_form = function() {
    var chart, end_quote, extremes, start_quote;
    chart = $('#template_chart').highcharts();
    extremes = chart.xAxis[0].getExtremes();
    start_quote = Math.ceil(extremes.min);
    end_quote = Math.floor(extremes.max);
    $('#template_match_start_quote_id').val(gon.ids[start_quote]);
    return $('#template_match_end_quote_id').val(gon.ids[end_quote]);
  };

  initPage = function() {
    $('select[flexible_select]').flexible_select();
    return $('#template_chart').each(function() {
      var categories, prices;
      prices = gon.prices;
      categories = gon.ids;
      return $(this).highcharts({
        chart: {
          zoomType: "x",
          events: {
            redraw: function() {
              return update_form();
            }
          }
        },
        title: {
          text: null
        },
        xAxis: {
          categories: categories,
          labels: {
            enabled: false
          }
        },
        yAxis: {
          title: {
            text: "Price",
            style: {
              color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1]
            }
          },
          opposite: true
        },
        tooltip: {
          shared: true
        },
        legend: {
          enabled: false
        },
        credits: {
          href: "http://www.pattern4all.com",
          text: "source: www.pattern4all.com"
        },
        series: [
          {
            name: "Price",
            data: prices,
            type: "line",
            marker: {
              enabled: false
            },
            tooltip: {
              valuePrefix: "$"
            },
            style: {
              color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1]
            }
          }
        ]
      });
    });
  };
}).call(this);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out that:

I needed to add

```
 //= require highcharts/modules/heatmap
```

to my `application.js` I thought it was a redundant inclusion, but apparently it's not.

Also the GEM readme, at: https://github.com/PerfectlyNormal/highcharts-rails mentions to install: `gem "highcharts-rails", "~> 3.0.0"` but 3.0.0 is not the latest version, I updated the gem inclusion to: `gem "highcharts-rails", "~> 4.1.9"`, which is currently the latest, and the problem seems fixed.

Even removing completely the version specification would work:

```
gem "highcharts-rails"
```

getting the project to use the latest version.

I'm going to make a pull request to update the readme.